# How can I use self attention similarity to trace reference in a sentence?

Tags: nlp, spacy, self-attention

In the following sentence: "Take a photo my friend and send to my wife."
I want to find the token "send" is referring to (i.e. "photo")
Can I to that using self attention, with Spacy ?

I suspect it could be a max self_attention_score(V_send, V_xx) = self_attention_score(V_send, V_photo)